# Laravel: SwiftMailer Class 'Lib\Services\Mail\Swift_Attachment' not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to use Swiftmailer in Laravel to send an attachment.  Here is my mailer class.

```
public function sendContactUsPrize(array $input, $fremail, $star, $name, $landing, $attachment)
    {
           //get contact us email for db


        if ($star)
        {
            Mail::send('Emails.ContactAct', $input, function($message) use($input, $fremail, $star, $name, $landing, $attachment)
            {
                   $message->to($star)
                           ->subject($name." has contacted you on https://seek.estate".$landing)
                           ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment));

                   $message->to($fremail)
                           ->subject($name." has submitted leads on https://seek.estate".$landing)
                           ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment));
            });
        }
    }
```

It keeps returning

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Class 'Lib\Services\Mail\Swift_Attachment' not found
```

I'm not sure where the Swiftmailer class is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `\Swift_Attachment::FromPath('FooBar')`

or

At the beginning add `use Swift_Attachment;`

Comment: Hey thanks, now im getting this error  ErrorException

fopen(Content-Type: application/pdf; name=53746a9ee9e85SellingAgreement.pdf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=53746a9ee9e85SellingAgreement.pdfJVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu

Comment: That's another question with different issues. But you figured that out yourself by asking a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910407/swiftmailer-sending-pdf . That was the proper way, people that have some experience with swiftmailer will answer there.