# Swiftmailer sending PDF

Tags: php, pdf, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer to send PDFs

I keep receiving this error

```
ErrorException

fopen(Content-Type: application/pdf; name=53746a9ee9e85SellingAgreement.pdf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=53746a9ee9e85SellingAgreement.pdf 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
```

This is my swift code

```
  $message->to($star)
     ->subject($name." has contacted you on https://seek.estate")
     ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('assets/docs/'.$attachment));
```

in my php.ini I have upload_max_filesize

post_max_size = 120M
allow_url_fopen =on

Not sure what could be causing this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue